# How to copy cell if condition is met and paste in another cell?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm completely stuck and needs someone to offer up some fresh code because I'm not even close to figuring this out. There are two things I need to do.

1. If M2>0 then copy M2 and paste it into D2.  Continue doing this until every cell in "M" has been evaluated based on row count.
2. Next, if I end up copying and pasting based on meeting condition then I want to also change Item Status in column F to say "FALSE".  Hope someone can help I'm at the tail end of a large project being completed.

Comment: Check this [StackOverflow question checklist](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) and edit your question accordingly. As is, your question is likely to be *downvoted* or worse, closed.

Answer (score 3):

For #1, In D2 put

```
=IF(M2>0,M2,"")
```

Then click and drag down the entire column

Then in F2 put

```
=IF(M2>0,"FALSE","TRUE")
```

Then click and drag down the entire column (assuming "TRUE" is what else is suppose to be in there.

In VBA, here's one way:

```
For i = 2 to ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
  If Range("M"&i).Value > 0 Then
    Range("D"&i).Value = Range("M"&i).Value
    Range("F"&i).Value = "FALSE"
Next i
```